# Cypress capture all requests cy.Route()

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image][image]

I want to capture all requests, however `cy.Route()` does not seem to accept wildcards. So, for example, I want to navigate to Reddit" and capture all the requests, however, I also want the code to be reusable so I can navigate to stack overflow and also capture all requests.

Is this possible?

I have tried * wildcard but it does not work

```js
cy.route('*').as('GETS');

cy.route(GET, '*').as('GETS');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Wait-on-url-matching-glob) automatically includes minimatch and exposes it as Cypress.minimatch. According to [minimatch documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch), you need to use `"Globstar" ** matching`

Correct ways for all `get` and `post` requests:

`cy.route('GET', '**').as('gets');`
`cy.route('POST', '**').as('posts');`

Or,

```
cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '**'
}).as('gets');


cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '**'
}).as('posts');
```

Note: `cy.route() should be set before cy.visit()`. To read the response use `cy.wait('@gets').then` and `cy.wait('@posts').then`

```
cy.wait('@posts').then((xhr) => {
    cy.log('Intercepted: ' + xhr.url);
    cy.log('Intercepted: ' + JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body));
});
```

Test on `www.google.com`:

[image: Test screenshot]

Test on `www.instagram.com`:
[image: Test screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for reply, however that doesn't work for me, lets use Instagram for an example, it does around 38 requests, mainly GET, none are captured.

CODE:
`it('Navigate', () => {
            cy.server();
            cy.visit('https://www.instagram.com');
            cy.route({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '**'
            }).as('GETS');

            cy.wait('@GETS').then((xhr) => {
                response_get = Number(JSON.stringify(xhr.duration));
            });
        });`

Comment: That's because you set the route after `.visit()`. I have tested it on `google.com`

Comment: @RichardSloman: I have added screenshots of tests on `'https://www.instagram.com'`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, still not working as you see it, that is exactly what i need also :-\

Cypress 4.7.0
Chrome 83
Windows 10

@Sree.Bh

Comment: I've also added a screenshot of code, i appreciate your help thank you

Comment: If you check the xhr calls on `www.instagram.com`, all are 'post' calls. I could not find any 'get' call there. I am using `Cypress 4.7.0 Chrome 83 in Mac`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215374/discussion-between-sree-bh-and-richard-sloman).